# Ignoring a group of TestCases in Nunit

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I have some selenium automation test cases written in C# using Nunit3. I wanted to run only a few test cases out of many. Those are basically sanity test cases. How can i achieve this. The entire solution will be run a VSTS so I do not want to run all the test cases every time. I want only sanity test cases to be run. How can i achieve this ..

Answer (score 1):

To run using the nunit console runner, assuming you have applied category "sanity" to the appropriate tests.

```
nunit3-console.exe mytests.dll --where "cat=sanity"
```

To do the same thing using the vstest runner

```
vstest.console.exe mytests.dll /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=sanity"
```

Comment: Im getting an error "'nunit3-console.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

nunit3-console.exe ClassLibrary2.dll --where "cat=sanity"

installed Nunit runner from Nuget Manager
Package Folder--> Open cmd prompt as administrator--> 
nunit3-console.exe ClassLibrary2.dll --where "cat=sanity"

Comment: Either you haven't installed the NUnit 3 Console runner or it's not in the directory where you are working or on your path.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same 'few tests' out of many that you want to run every time? If so I'd suggest separating those 'few tests' into a separate project under the same solution.

There are other ways to achieve what you want i.e. using @tags but from what you have said moving those tests to a separate project will be the easiest and most efficient way to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes I want these few test cases out of many to run once. Basically these are sanity test cases . If these pass then I want to run the rest of the test cases. If these few test cases fail I dont want to run the other test cases

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using VSTS to execute the tests you can group the tests using traits(test category)

[image]

You can exclude the category or group you do now want to execute while running the tests from Test Explorer.

Do you know you can run the tests from the command prompt as well? It is even easier to ignore the test cases of a specific category. The following mstest command will execute all the tests in the MyTestProjectName dll except the category - IgnoredGroupName

```
mstest /testcontainer:MyTestprojectName.dll /category:"!IgnoredGroupName"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working with Nunit. Is it possible to run a particular group of test in cmd prompt using Nunit.. If so please provide some detailed steps..using Nunit dont forget.